# Azure function app deployment error "Encountered an error (ServiceUnavailable) from host runtime. (CODE: 400)"

Tags: azure, devops, azure-function-app

My python file is in Azure devops repository. I am trying to deploy it to the azure function app and execute the py file. I already building up an service connection "testing" to connect the resource group.
My code is following.

steps:

- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
  displayName: 'Azure Function App Deploy: api'
  inputs:
  azureSubscription: testing
  appType: functionAppLinux
  appName: api
  package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
  runtimeStack: 'DOCKER|microsoft/azure-functions-dotnet-core3.0:3.0'
  startUpCommand: 'func azure functionapp publish $(functionAppName) --no-bundler'

However, i encounter error ##[error]Error: Failed to sync triggers for function app 'api'. Error: BadRequest - Encountered an error (ServiceUnavailable) from host runtime. (CODE: 400)

Answer (score 7):

This might help: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5722

I had the same issue and removing WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE from siteConfig.appSettings fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up to Balint's answer, I had something similar happen which started causing this same problem. In my case I'm using keyvault secrets in my configuration to load some keys, and this failed until I refreshed my config.